# How to speed up simulation time of simulink for fuzzy controllers

Tags: simulink, fuzzy-logic

I have implemented fuzzy controller in simulink as shown below. Fuzzy controller has two inputs with three membership functions and 9 rules.The issue is that; that the simulink is taking too long time to run it. What could be the issue. Any guidance.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried Simulink profiler and/or Simulink performance advisor?

Comment: I have tried it but I am not getting clear understanding of the report I have received after running the model by selecting simulink profiler.How simulink profiler would help me; as I am very new to simulink so I am having no idea of it.

Comment: Total recorded time: 154.39 s Number of Block Methods: 158 Number of Internal Methods: 10 Number of Nonvirtual Subsystem Methods: 5 Clock precision: 0.00000005 s Clock Speed: 2200 MHz                             These are the initial parameters I got in the report.

Comment: Any guidance regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

go to configuration parameters --> solver --> zero crossing option and turn it to disable, it would help you.